# SuperLU with OpenBLAS: undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'

Tags: openblas

When compiling the SuperLU 4.3 library using OpenBLAS instead of regular BLAS distributions, this error keeps coming up:

```
>gcc  cdrive.o sp_cconvert.o cgst01.o cgst02.o cgst04.o cgst07.o sp_ienv.o \
>   libtmglib.a /a/location/lib/libsuperlu_4.3.a ->L/a/location/lib/libopenblas.a -lopenblas -lm -o ctest
>/a/location/lib/libopenblas.a(memory.o): In function >'openblas_fork_handler':
>memory.c:(.text+0x3e0): undefined reference to 'pthread_atfork'
>/a/location/lib/libopenblas.a(blas_server.o): In function >'blas_thread_shutdown_':
>blas_server.c:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to 'pthread_join'
>/a/location/lib/libopenblas.a(blas_server.o): In function >'goto_set_num_threads':
>blas_server.c:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to 'pthread_create'
>/a/location/lib/libopenblas.a(blas_server.o): In function >'blas_thread_init':
>blas_server.c:(.text+0x721): undefined reference to 'pthread_create'
```

Comment: You need to link pthread / libpthread. This might be done automatically, but not in your case. What's your linker?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link pthread / libpthread. Depending on the linker, this might be done automatically, but not in your case.